# how to display display 1 record IF 2 same id to lrid & refno to search on 2nd ID record in sql

Tags: sql

Example:

```
Lr_id
 11
 12
 13

Ref_no
 11
```

IN Table if match found in ref_no so display record of 12 otherwise 11.
Same Id like lr_id = 11 & Ref_no=11 so i want display record of lr_id =12 because ref_no = 11 assign to lr_id. Otherwise display as it is lr_id record.

SQL QUERY:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Track_LR_history]                
@GCno as varchar(100),            
@reference_no as varchar(100)            
AS             
declare @qry as varchar(max)            
declare @cond as varchar(max)            
declare @finalqry as varchar(max)            
set @qry = 'SELECT l.lr_id AS GCno, l.creation_dt AS Date, Party.ConsignorName   AS Consignor, Party.ConsigneeName AS Consignee, offi.branch_name AS Bookingbranch, '            
set @qry = @qry + 'dbo.TBL_BRANCH.branch_name AS CurrentBranch, tost.branch_name AS DestinationBranch, TBL_APP_LIST_ELM_1.name AS CollType, '            
set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_APP_LIST_ELM.name AS Deltype, TBL_APP_LIST_ELM_2.name AS PayType, l.reporting_date AS ReportingDate,  case when isnull(l.stax_applicable_to2app_elm,0) =268435545 then  isnull(chgamt.Booking,0) + isnull(l.ser_tax,0) else  isnull(chgamt.Booking,0) end AS BookingAmt, '            
set @qry = @qry + ' l.invoice_no AS Invno, l.lr_total_qty AS Qty, l.lr_total_weight AS Weight, l.entry_date, l.reference_no,dbo.TBL_BUS_CUST.cust_name AS FranchiseName, l.challan_no '            
set @qry = @qry + ' FROM dbo.TBL_LR_HEAD AS l INNER JOIN  dbo.TBL_BUS_CUST AS cr ON l.lr_cor2bc_cust = cr.row_id INNER JOIN '            
set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_BUS_CUST AS ce ON l.lr_con2bc_cust = ce.row_id INNER JOIN  dbo.TBL_BRANCH AS offi ON l.lr_frm2branch = offi.row_id INNER JOIN '            
set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_BRANCH AS tost ON l.lr_to2branch = tost.row_id INNER JOIN  dbo.TBL_BRANCH ON l.lr_current_br2site = dbo.TBL_BRANCH.row_id INNER JOIN '            
set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_APP_LIST_ELM ON l.lr_del_typ2app_elm = dbo.TBL_APP_LIST_ELM.row_id INNER JOIN  dbo.TBL_APP_LIST_ELM AS TBL_APP_LIST_ELM_1 ON l.lr_coll_typ2coll_typ = TBL_APP_LIST_ELM_1.row_id INNER JOIN '            
set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_APP_LIST_ELM AS TBL_APP_LIST_ELM_2 ON l.lr_payment_type2app_elm = TBL_APP_LIST_ELM_2.row_id LEFT OUTER JOIN '    
set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_BUS_CUST ON l.lr_franchise2bus_cust = dbo.TBL_BUS_CUST.row_id Left outer join'        
set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_USER   WITH (NOLOCK) ON l.lr_create2user = dbo.TBL_USER.row_id  left outer join  (select    SUM(dbo.TBL_LR_CHARGES.amount)  aS Booking,lr_chrg_item2lr_head  from TBL_LR_CHARGES  WITH (NOLOCK) where   '          

set @qry = @qry + ' dbo.TBL_LR_CHARGES.lr_chrg_bp2app_elm in ( 268435565)  '                   
set @qry = @qry + ' AND  lr_chrg_hd2chrg_hd <> 268435605 and lr_chrg_hd2chrg_hd <> 268435606  '                            
set @qry = @qry + ' and  lr_chrg_hd2chrg_hd <> 268435607 and lr_chrg_hd2chrg_hd <> 268435608 and   '                            
set @qry = @qry + ' lr_chrg_hd2chrg_hd <> 268435609  group by  lr_chrg_item2lr_head)  as  chgamt  on chgamt.lr_chrg_item2lr_head = l.row_id   '                
set @qry = @qry + ' left outer join View_LrConsrConse Party with (nolock) ON Party.Row_id = L.Row_id '  


if @GCno<>''                                
begin  

set @cond= ' where l.lr_id = '''+ @GCno +'''' 
--set @cond= ' where l.lr_id = '''+ @GCno +'+ OR +'+(select lr_id from TBL_LR_HEAD where reference_no=@reference_no)+''             
end                                 


if @reference_no<>''                                
 begin                                 
  if @cond=''  or     @cond is null                          
   begin                                 
   set @cond= ' where l.reference_no = '''+ @reference_no +''''                                
  end                                
  else                                
   begin 

    set @cond= @cond + ' and l.reference_no = '''+ @reference_no +''''                                
  end                                
end    


exec  (@qry + @cond)
```

Thank you.

Comment: How to display on perticular ref_no...otherwise display on lr_id...     Example: Lr_id 11 12 13 Ref_no 11

IN Table if match found in ref_no so display record of 12 otherwise 11.

Thank you.

Comment: sir... question modified... please check & reply ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go out on a limb and attempt an answer.  It looks like you want to use the value from the `Ref_no` column if present (not `NULL`), otherwise use the value from the `lr_id` column.  The `COALESCE` function does precisely this.  Consider this query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Ref_no, lr_id)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: this gives error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: sir... question modified... please check & reply...thanks for helping...